# Grafana Simple JSON response for Single Stat Panel

Tags: python, json, grafana

I'm using Grafana 3.0 beta 5 and Simple JSON datasource plugin. I'm trying to implement a backend in Python that gathers business information from my ERP.

I know that Grafana Simple JSON expects 4 REST methods:

- /
- query
- search
- annotation

The Simple JSON datasource plugin has not too much documentation, I know that it's on early development.

I'm looking for someone that could point me for some JSON response sample to the Single Stat panel of Grafana.

Another thing, Grafana probably passes some parameters to the query method, I'm wondering which one are those parameters.

Thanks in advance,

Best regards

Comment: did you get anything or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected response would be similar to this - https://gist.github.com/tral/1fe649455fe2de9fb8fe except that you would have only one "target".

Grafana passes the options object to the query method. Here's what it would look like for a single stat panel.
[image: grafana test]